# Chaining decorators

Tags: python

I am trying to chaining two decorators . but some how end up running only one. can some one suggest me solution for that

```
def decorator_redis(func_name):
    def redis_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def redis_wrapper(*args):
            redis_utilty = RedisUtilties()
            entity_id = args[0]
            return 'hello' + entity_id
        return redis_wrapper
    return redis_decorator

def decorator_ES(func_name):
    def ES_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def ES_wrapper(*args):
            return args[0]+ '!'
        return ES_wrapper
    return ES_decorator

@decorator_redis('find')
@decorator_ES('find')
def fetch_entity(name):
    return

print(fetch_entity('John'))
```

I need to print `hello John!`. But able to print out `hello John` or `John !` depending on which decorator I used individually.

Comment: Your indentation seems wrong. Please reindent your code.

Comment: Why do you have decorator factories? Neither of your decorators use the `func_name` parameter.

Comment: The basic problem is that neither wrapper calls the orginal `func()`; you have effectively bypassed the decorated function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the decorated function in the decorator's wrapper (each of them):

```
def decorator_ES(func_name):
    def ES_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def ES_wrapper(*args):
            return func(args[0]+ '!')  # <-- HERE
        return ES_wrapper
    return ES_decorator
```

Same for another decorator.

Otherwise, you effectively *replace* the function with the latest (topmost) wrapper. So, when you call it, it never gets to the bottom decorator or to the function itself.